# Getting NULL argument in MVC controller during Ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax post in which I send JSON string data, but I get null in my controller.

AJAX Call:

```
 var jsonData = JSON.stringify(matrixPresenter);
        $.post("/matrix/Savematrix?matrixData=" + jsonData , function (result) {

        });
```

This is which I get when I keep my debugger on jsonData:

```
"{"tagList":[{"tagId":"16","name":"White","isEnable":"true"},{"tagId":"19","name":"Night","isEnable":"true"}],"captureCategoryTypeId":" 5051"}"
```

but when I keep debugger in my controller I see matrixData as null in
my Controller method:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Savematrix(string matrixData)
        {
            if (matrixData != null)
            {
            //do something
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
            //do something
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Looks like I am missing here something.

Comment: You are passing data instead of jsonData in your post ?

Comment: Ooops typos during posting question, rectified.Its Jsondata.

Comment: Why are you posting back a `string` rather than binding to a model?

Comment: As I am reading those data from partial view and saving them on main form without making complete page being sent to server.

Comment: What does that have to do with it. The parameter in your method should be a model representing what your sending. And the code you have shown works fine (tested and its not `null`)

Comment: I tried that with model too, but I was getting null , later I changed to string just to see its not deserialization issue.

Comment: If its `null`, it has nothing to do with the code you have shown, because what you have shown works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be a problem with the way you're constructing the JSON object for `matrixPresenter`. Could you please try replacing your view with the code below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnOK").click(function () {
            var matrixPresenter =
                {
                    tagList:
                        [
                            { "tagId": "16", "name": "White", "isEnable": "true" },
                            { "tagId": "19", "name": "Night", "isEnable": "true" }
                        ],
                    captureCategoryTypeId: 5051
                };
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(matrixPresenter);
            $.post("/matrix/Savematrix?matrixData=" + jsonData, function (result) {
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnOK" value="OK" />
```